# Block regsvr32 using AppLocker only for normal users

Tags: applocker

I am trying to block the execution of regsvr32 by normal domain users. I have the default rule which allows to everyone the execute all files located in windows folder.

Now I would like to deny the execution for regsvr32 to anybody who is not local admin.

I tried to create such a rule in Applocker but I didn't succeed.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.